# How to get MongoDB version from Ruby code using Mongoid or Mongo Ruby Driver?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I have a Rails app with MongoDB. I need to dynamically display current MongoDB version on the status webpage. It's important for my client to know whether it's `3.0`, `3.2` or `3.4` version.

However, I can't find this value anywhere. I'm using `pry` to debug the connection details and I've already tried any relevant public method from `Mongoid` and `Mongo` class hierarchy without success.

The canonical way to do this with pure MongoDB is `db.version()`, but it seems there is no way to send this raw query with Mongoid.

Comment: Run the database command for [`"buildInfo"`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/buildInfo/#dbcmd.buildInfo). `'version'` is then a property of the returned data structure.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should do the following call (Mongoid 5+):

```
Mongoid.default_client.command(buildInfo: 1).first[:version]
```

Or, in earlier versions:

```
Mongoid.default_session.command(buildinfo: 1)["version"]
```

(Answer updated according to @yeasayer comment)

Comment: This outputs `2.4.0`, but my MongoDB version is `3.4.5`

Comment: [yeasayer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/458758/yeasayer) I've just updated the answer by including the right call.

Comment: Settled on `Mongoid.default_client.command(buildInfo: 1).first[:version]` for modern Mongoid > 5